# How to add custom component in pallete of android studio

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-studio-3.0

I want to know if there any way to add custom UI components in palette. 
[image]

I tried searching in documentation, but i could not find any such option.
It seems like IntelliJ IDEA has this [option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/palette.html), but i could not see it in Android Studio.

Comment: have you tried creating custom views? https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: yes i have. I am trying to develop a ui design library. I wanted to show custom components in Designer palette of android studio so that the developer can easily drag and drop my custom views to layouts.

Comment: As an alternate, use Advanced > view to select custom view. Some functions seems lost in updates of Android Studio.  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/android-studio-2-3.html > Layout Editor Palette: The updated widget palette ... (It was http://tools.android.com/recent/customviewsinthepalette )